Ag-Grid Filter Based on User Parameters
I'm wondering if there is a way to automatically filter the data that is returned, based on parameters specified in json file.  If I use the ag-grid link https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/component-filter/ as an example, let's say the user has a country parameter of "Australia" and I only want them to see athletes from Australia, but this filter should automatically be applied when the user logs into the application.  This would actually be role based access control, but applied to the data return by ag-grid.
So far I haven't tried anything, because I'm not even sure where to begin with this.  I'm pretty new to ag-grid, but I took over an application and now one of the requirements is to limit the data returned based on user roles.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
